# How to add tabs control in Elementor

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I want to add a tab control like that:

[image]

Can you tell me which control I should use?

Here is the list of controls: https://developers.elementor.com/docs/controls/

Comment: Anyways: I found it: https://developers.elementor.com/docs/controls/control-tabs/

Answer (score 1):

As I can see from your picture, you want to add a tab inside your Elementor widget.
Add the code given below inside your widget to make a tab view in the Elementor Widget.

```
<?php 

$this->start_controls_tabs(
    'data_style_tabs'
);

$this->start_controls_tab(
  'data_style_normal_tab',
  [
    'label' => __( 'Normal', 'textdomain' ),
  ]
);
// Add your controls here
$this->add_control();

$this->end_controls_tab();

$this->start_controls_tab(
  'data_style_hover_tab',
  [
    'label' => __( 'Hover', 'textdomain' ),
  ]
);
// Add your controls here
$this->add_control();

$this->end_controls_tab();

$this->end_controls_tabs();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To add tab controls you need to take the help of a custom plugin. You can add tab controls or widgets as you wish to the custom plugin. Follow the URL below to structure your custom plugin.
https://github.com/elementor/elementor-hello-world

Plugin Structure:

```
assets/
      /js   
      /css  Holds plugin CSS Files
      
widgets/
      /hello-world.php
      /inline-editing.php
      
index.php
elementor-hello-world.php
plugin.php
```